# no me deja mover mis archivos php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

quiero poder copiar y pegar en la ruta de un dia anterior ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esa ruta si me la ejecuta bien y me crea la carpeta pero cuando yo quiero que se mueva el txt no lo hace pero cuanod quito la variable de fecha este si me lo arroja y si me deja guardarlo en la ruta solo sin la fecha pero con la carpeta fecha no lo copia

este es un var_dump

string(42) "\10.100.99.74\c\xampp\htdocs\post1\ 20 Oct"

```
<?php

$from = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\post\aqui.txt*.*';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

$fecha=strftime("%d %h");


$to = '\\10.100.99.74\c\xampp\htdocs\post1\ '.$fecha;
exec('copy '.$from.' '.$to.' /Y');

if (!file_exists($to)) {
    mkdir($to, 0777, true);
}

var_dump($to);
```

me muestra la carpeta asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la carpeta destino contiene espacios y deberías encerrarla entre comillas. Prefiero encerrar cadenas entre comillas dobles para que PHP interprete las variables en vez de concatenar. Hay caracteres que necesitan escaparse, agregando `\` antes.

**Nota:** No me había dado cuenta de que estás haciendo la validación después de copiar y debe ser antes. Si especificas una ruta que no existe, Windows "entenderá" que debe copiar todo en un archivo.

```
<?php
$from = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\post\aqui.txt*.*';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

$fecha=strftime("%d %h");
$to = '\\10.100.99.74\c\xampp\htdocs\post1\ '.$fecha;

// Validar primero si existe y es directorio
if (!file_exists($to) || !is_dir($to)) {
    // Verifica que realmente se creó la carpeta
    if(!mkdir($to, 0777, true)) {
       die("No se puede crear la carpeta $to");
    }
}
exec("copy $from \"$to\" /Y");
```

El único problema que puede tener tu *script* es que en Windows no se aplican los cambios de permisos con [`mkdir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mkdir).

Comment: ahora otra duda como te doy más de 1000 puntos gracias!!

Comment: otra pregunta por que me deja la carpeta blanca mira lo puse en mi pregunta ya que la edite y asi me muestra la carpeta

Comment: si me dice archivo el icono

Comment: y me dice Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\catchClab.php on line 11

Comment: si ya valide eso copie y 'pege de forma manual archivos

Comment: ya los tengo y tambien los sigue pegando en blanco como si fuera un archivo

Comment: Listo, revisa la actualización de la respuesta, ahí te explico porqué falla la copia.

Comment: Ah, se me olvidaba, borrar el archivo, porque si tiene el mismo nombre no te va a dejar crear la carpeta.

Comment: pero como puedo hacer que lo tome de una red compartida-Warning: fileperms(): stat failed for \10.100.14.12\Sterling\Recibe\R200_CMG.txt*.* in C:\xampp\htdocs\catchClab.php on line 49